# Vue3 loading blobs when I hover an SVG

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have this Vue component which returns the svg code for the icons that I use:

```
<template>
    <div :class="attributes.class" v-html="icon"></div>
</template>

<script>
import {ref, onMounted} from "vue";
import axios from "axios";

const iconCache = new Map();

export default {
    name: "Icon",
    props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            default: "slash-circle-01",
        },
    },
    setup(props) {
        const icon = ref("");
        const attributes = ref({class: "shrink-0"});

        async function fetchIcon(iconName) {
            if (iconCache.has(iconName)) {
                return iconCache.get(iconName);
            }

            try {
                const {data} = await axios.get(`/assets/icons/${iconName}.svg`);
                iconCache.set(iconName, data);
                return data;
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
                // Avoid refetching the default icon if it's already fetched or the error wasn't about the icon not being found
                if (iconName !== "slash-circle-01" && !iconCache.has("slash-circle-01")) {
                    return fetchIcon("slash-circle-01");
                }
            }
        }

        onMounted(async () => {
            icon.value = await fetchIcon(props.name);
        });

        return {icon, attributes};
    },
};
</script>
```

It renders correctly but whenever I hover these icons and move the mouse over them, I see blobc in the Inspect > Network tab and I don't have any idea why it does this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because Vue's reactivity with the usage of `v-html` to render the SVG code.

When you use `v-html` Vue creates a dynamic component and updates its content whenever the underlying icon changes. When you hover over the icons, it might trigger a re-render which could result in Vue fetching the SVG again and creating a new blob URI.